# How to know if npm package supports Angular x version?

Tags: angular, typescript

My project has lots of dependencies on libraries that supports Angular2, but not Angular6 for ex. Now I find it difficult to accurately tell from reading their github pages do they support Angular2. One thought - look at package.json typescript version - if bellow 2.7.2 (lowest Angular6 typescript version), it absolutelly does not support Angular6. Is that right? How to know from github page does library support Angular6?

Comment: just upgrade angular and see 1. npm warnings about wrong dependencies 2. what's not compiling with typescript 3. what's not working in the app. That's the only reliable way

Comment: The strongest indicator would be the version requirements of angular packages in `peerDependencies` in `package.json`.

Comment: Thanks @Jota.Toledo - that what I am asking. So if peer is `"@angular/core": ">= 5.0.0",` - it wont support Angular6?

Comment: @youBetterBeRight as mentioned, is just an indicator. If you install a lib with such peer, you will get a warning, but the lib API may not have been affected by the changes in angular from v5 to v6.

Comment: Thanks @Jota.Toledo, seems this is the only way to guess for dependency...

Answer (score 0):

Important Point to move angular to higher angular version

1) Remove all node modules 
2) Always make backup of app folder
3) Install angular latest version using cli (ex 4, 6) -  ng new projectname 
4) install all third party dependencies individually which are listed in package.json of angular 2 project ex. [lodash , primeng, ] using npm install  -- save
5) **please don't install all core modules of angular using npm. it automatically add while add new project using ng new command. ex ("@angular/forms" ,"@angular/http", "@angular/platform-browser")**

it is best way to convert angular 2 to angular higher version

Comment: It was not the question I asked. I asked how to know if library supports Angular6 (without deeply inspecting its code, or evcen trying to implement it)

Comment: And what do you mean - **please don't install all core modules of angular using npm. it automatically add while add new project using ng new command** - I won't use `ng new` as I am upgrading version of the current project

Comment: Just i said one way to convert angular 2 to it is higher version.it is my way usually convert.mighy you want to do differently

Comment: Check all depencies in package.json try to install packege individuals via core moule upgrade. Ex. npm i @angular/forms

Comment: Majorly core angular will make you issue to work..try to  recompile once, check which moudle makes you problem & try to upgrade it manually..it is other way where no need require install angular 6 .hope it will help